# Active link name is not changing color in bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a single-page website currently I am working on. But When I click another link in the navbar it's not changing color though hovering is working perfectly. Here is my html code :

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 ">
<li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link scroll active " aria-current="page" href="#intro">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#about">About Us </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#">Products</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHQIh.png)

Here is my css:

```
<style>
.navbar .nav-item a {
  color: #5cbf8f !important;
}

.navbar .nav-item a:hover {
  color: #028b77 !important;
}

.navbar .nav-item a.active {
  color: #028b77 !important;
}
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgVAn.png)

Here is my Js :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scrollLink = $(".scroll");

  // Smooth scrolling
  scrollLink.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body,html").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top,
      },
      1000
    );
  });

  // Active link switching
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function () {
      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;

      if (sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSdyR.png)

N.B: Don't really know about js, just found it on the internet.

Navbar:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIYW0.png)

Comment: please post code snippets instead of screenshots of it

Answer (score 0):

I think your js is wrong.

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

More efficient options are available if the DOM hierarchy is known.

For example, if they're all siblings, you can use this:

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: So I just have to put that code in my script tag or could you be more specific

Comment: I have some questions about your post.

Comment: First: Changing color in hover is not working or active is not working?

Comment: changing color in hover is working but active is not working

Comment: Got it, So I think The javascript has some bugs

Comment: If you share your code with snippet, I can solve that soon.

Comment: Here is my html code https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#sa96p5zsxgaumlt7n9woy

Comment: You can reference https://codepen.io/Holmesc16/pen/VzwVRZ.

Comment: Here is css : https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#9d3qz8yj9jjlijjavka04

Comment: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#wm70nmjagzgl0bftb618o here is js

Comment: I think $this.removeClass('inactive').addClass("active");
   $this.siblings().addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
}); is important for you.

Comment: Here i how connected js with my idndex page :

Comment: <!-- Template Main Javascript File -->

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<!--Importing Bootstrap (Poper)-->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!--Importing Bootstrap (Java Script)-->

<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

Comment: You can use  $this.addClass("active"); $this.siblings().removeClass('active'); instead of $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");